# Re-initialize variables in customized loss function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I defined a customized regularizer `my_reg`, and its loss function involves a variable `z`.

```py
def __call__(loss):
    z = K.variable(value=w)  # I need z to be initialized every time
    z = K.print_tensor(z, message='time1: ')

    # BELOW: SOME COMPUTATION THAT WILL RANDOMLY UPDATE z
    n_freeze = SOME_FIXED_VALUE
    idx = tf.range(tf.shape(z)[0])
    random_choice = tf.random_shuffle(idx)[:n_freeze]
    z = K.variable(z)
    z = tf.scatter_update(z, random_choice, np.zeros((n_freeze, x_cols)))
    # ABOVE: SOME COMPUTATION THAT WILL RANDOMLY UPDATE z

    z = K.print_tensor(z, message='time2: ')

    regularized_loss += #some computation involves z#

    z = K.print_tensor(z, message='time3: ')
```

I hope z can be re-initialized every time the loss function is called, i.e. every time `z=K.variable(value=w)` needs to be run. However, each time the printed output only involves `time2:`, and `z` seems not re-initialized each time. How can I achieve that?

---

EDIT: INCLUDE **INIT** FUNCTION:

```py
class my_reg(Regularizer):
    def __init__(self, scale, gamma, b, cnn=False, detector=None, test=True, batch_size=50):
        self.scale = scale
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.b = b
        self.cnn = cnn
        self.w = None
        self.p = None
        self.detector = detector
        self.test = test
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        # training flag
        self.uses_learning_phase = True

        # whether or not use secret_X dropout
        self.dropout = 0.25
```

Comment: to the initialize(_init__) of this class, did you receive a parameter model which refers to the model ? may be you can set it using that reference

Comment: Hi venkata, thanks for your response! You mean I need to set z to be one of the attribute of the class `my_reg`?

Comment: in your class my_reg, you must be having an __ init __ function, which is being called during while initializing right ? can you share how do you set your custom regularizer to the model ?

Comment: Hi venkata, I added my __init__ function above. Those are just some necessary attribute assign.

Comment: have you gone through the discussion in this github thread https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9100

Comment: Why not have a random tensor of zeros or ones and simply multiply it by z instead of "updating" z? The only problem is that you use `update` instead of creating a new tensor. (No, tensorflow will not create `z` more than once, that is not how it works)

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks for your explanation! May I ask how to generate a new tensor matrix with `random_choice` of index to be all zeros and all other index to be ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `update`. Just create new tensors:

```
zero_probability = n_freeze/tf.shape(z)[0]

drop = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(z)[:1])   
drop = tf.cast(tf.greater(drop, zero_probability), tf.float32)

z = drop * z
```